# Como montar consultas customizada usando Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

Possuo um banco SQL Server que é acessado via ORM Entity Framework Core, onde acesso uma coleção de produtos, estes produtos são filtrados através de um DTO que possui os termos da busco, que pode ser composta ou simples, exemplo: o cliente pode informar na busca somente o Nome do produto ou Nome, Material de fabricação e UF.

A questão é como montar uma *query* legível que abarque todos os cenários customizáveis?

DTO de pesquisa:

```
public class DtoPesquisaProduto
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public string Material { get; set; }

    public EstadosEnum? Estado { get; set; }

    public decimal PrecoInicial { get; set; }

    public decimal PrecoFinal { get; set; }
}
```

A Consulta:

```
_context.Produtos 
.Where(x => x.Nome == pesquisa.Nome 
    && x.Material == pesquisa.Material 
    && x.Estado == pesquisa.Estado 
    && (x.Preco >= pesquisa.PrecoInicial && x.Preco <= pesquisa.PrecoFinal)) 
 .ToListAsync();
```

A consulta `Where` deve ser dinâmica considerando somente a expressão cujo valor for diferente de nulo.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Um coisa que poucas pessoas entendem é que o LINQ é um construtor de expressões. Ele não está executando tudo aquilo de uma só vez, ele faz um passo de cada vez, desde que esteja em métodos diferentes. Seu código é, em essência, o mesmo que:

```
IQueryable<Produtos> query = _context.Produtos;
query = query.Where(x => x.Nome == pesquisa.Nome);
query = query.Where(x => x.Material == pesquisa.Material);
query = query.Where(x => x.Estado == pesquisa.Estado);
query = query.Where(x => x.Preco >= pesquisa.PrecoInicial && x.Preco <= pesquisa.PrecoFinal);
resultado = query.ToListAsync();
```

Agora basta colocar um `if` para cada linha para decidir se a expressão vai entrar ou não. Exemplo:

```
IQueryable<Produtos> query = _context.Produtos;
if (pesquisa.Nome != null) query = query.Where(x => x.Nome == pesquisa.Nome);
if (pesquisa.Material != null) query = query.Where(x => x.Material == pesquisa.Material);
... //aqui coloca tudo o que deseja
resultado = await query.ToListAsync();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/EntityFramework/QueryCompose.cs).

E pense se realmente o `Async()` é a melhor opção, em muitos casos ele fica pior, especialmente se não for usado se forma correta. E se questione se esta é a hora certa para dar o `ToList()`, é muito comum que as pessoas deem antes do que deve por não entender o LINQ. `_` não é idiomático em C#. Mas essas são outras questões.

Isto funciona bem para casos puramente de *and*, mas se precisa algo mais complexo aí pode usar um [*predicate builder*](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) ou [biblioteca que construa dinamicamente para você](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Comment: Sinceridade eu trabalho com EF a muito tempo e isso que está explicado acima não faz muito sentido, eu queria realmente entender antes de colocar uma opinião plausivel, visto que o ToListAsync no final do código não terá os filtros posteriores! A resposta mais correta é ao do Marcelo que levou votos negativos sem necessidade (talvez por causa do IEnumerable, talvez)

Comment: Eu questionei o `ToListAsync()`, apenas deixei o que ele está fazendo.  De fato eu esqueci de colocar a atribuição. Bom você ter questionado porque eu não tinha percebido. A do Marcelo usa `HasValue` em campos que claramente são por referência, e tem um método que só ele sabe o que faz, e o erro que você apontou. então não sei como isto pode ser certo.

Comment: Bom `_context` não seria uma atribuição legal, é a variável `DBContext`, deve ser feita para outra variável mediante pergunta. Posso concordar que tem alguns pontos que melhora a resposta do amigo, mas, em compensação a dele antes era a mais próxima da realidade, inclusive Maniero, tem duplicata, eu já vi, mas, não encontro pelo sistema de busca.

Comment: Acho que tem razão. Se tiver algo mais que viu de errado eu melhoro. Obrigado pelos questionamentos, só colaborou pra um resultado melhor para todos. Realmente a busca é ruim ,se achar marca lá que eu termino de fechar.

Comment: Maniero para essa sua função funcionar você tem que alterar de IQueryable<Produto> para IQueryable<Produtos> e alterar de query.Produtos.Where para query.Where depois nas query subsequentes.

Comment: @LucianoOiticicaLemgruber sim, tinha esses erros e corrigi agora, obrigado, eu reconheço meus erros e quem me ajuda. Só não entendi porque o mesmo erro em outra resposta recebe parabéns.

Answer (score 3):

Os `.Where(this IEnumerable<T>, Predicate<T>)` são carregados *preguiçosamente*, ou seja, não são processados no momento da declaração, mas sim quando a consulta final (o resultado final do `.Where()`) é iterada.

```
IQueryable<Produto> query = _context.Produtos;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pesquisa.Nome))
{
    query = query.Where(where => where.Nome == pesquisa.Nome);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pesquisa.Material))
{
    query = query.Where(where => where.Material == pesquisa.Material);
}

if (pesquisa.Estado.HasValue)
{
    query = query.Where(where => where.Estado == pesquisa.Estado.Value);
}

// ... assim por diante, para cada propriedade

return query.ToList(); // Materializa query.
```

Comment: `IEnumerable<Produto> query = _context.Produtos;` o correto seria `IQueryable<Produto> query = context.Produtos;`, se mudar isso a sua resposta é a correta e o mais engraçado levar votos negativos.

Comment: Por questão de ética e igualdade, porque colocar um `return Mapear(query)` em sua resposta? não faz parte da pergunta original, e também não faz parte de um método ou classe da sua pergunta, poderia explicar ou até remover colocando um `query.ToList()` no final. ?

Comment: Concordo com o Virgilio Novic essa é a melhor resposta, reformulei a minha resposta com base nos seus comentários Virgilio Novic.

Comment: @LucianoOiticicaLemgruber nem o Virgilo concorda, ele apresentou dois problemas nela, e eu apresentei um mais. De qualquer forma obrigado por concordar com a minha resposta já que a nova versão da sua faz o mesmo que está na minha.

Comment: Alterado para `IQueryable<Produto>`.

Comment: Alterado para `query.ToList();`.

Answer (score 0):

Olá Ricardo boa noite.

Vamos lá você deve querer isso dentro de uma mesma consulta correto ?

para isso você deve usar um operador ternário

```
await _context.Produtos 
.Where(x => pesquisa.Nome != null ? x.Nome == pesquisa.Nome : false)
.Where(x => pesquisa.Material  != null ? x.Material == pesquisa.Material : false)
.Where(x => pesquisa.Estado != null ? x.Estado == pesquisa.Estado : false)
.Where(x => pesquisa.PrecoInicial != null ? x.Preco >= pesquisa.PrecoInicial : false)
.Where(x => pesquisa.PrecoFinal != null ? x.Preco <= pesquisa.PrecoFinal : false)
.ToListAsync();
```

Um pouco sobre operador ternário com o Mestre Macoratti
http://www.macoratti.net/14/11/c_tern1.htm

Dessa forma irá procurar por todos os atributos na mesma consulta.

**UPDATE**

Peço desculpas tinha colocado um true no final que pega valores nulos da tabela.

Utilize o false que ele não vai buscar valores nulos da tabela.

Segue abaixo exemplo da query gerada em uma **tabela minha** com o true

```
.Where(x => pesquisa.PrecoInicial != null ? x.Preco >= pesquisa.PrecoInicial : true)

SELECT [a].[ViaturasID],[a].[ValorPrestacao]
FROM [Viaturas] AS [a]
WHERE ((@__prestacaoInicial_0 IS NOT NULL AND ([a].[ValorPrestacao] >= @__prestacaoInicial_1)) OR @__prestacaoInicial_0 IS NULL) AND ((@__prestacaoFinal_2 IS NOT NULL AND ([a].[ValorPrestacao] <= @__prestacaoFinal_3)) OR @__prestacaoFinal_2 IS NULL)
```

e com o false

```
.Where(x => pesquisa.PrecoInicial != null ? x.Preco >= pesquisa.PrecoInicial : false)

SELECT [a].[ViaturasID],[a].[ValorPrestacao]
FROM [Viaturas] AS [a]
WHERE (@__prestacaoInicial_0 IS NOT NULL AND ([a].[ValorPrestacao] >= @__prestacaoInicial_1)) AND (@__prestacaoFinal_2 IS NOT NULL AND ([a].[ValorPrestacao] <= @__prestacaoFinal_3))
```

**================ NOVA SOLUÇÃO ================**

Me baseando nos comentários do Virgilio Novic realmente vi que assim vai ficar mais eficaz a consulta.

Sendo que isso veio tudo a partir da resposta do Marcelo Uchimura.

```
IQueryable<Produtos> query = _context.Produtos;

if (pesquisa.Nome != null)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Nome == pesquisa.Nome);
}
if (pesquisa.Material  != null)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Material == pesquisa.Material);
}
if (pesquisa.Estado != null)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Estado == pesquisa.Estado);
}
if (pesquisa.PrecoInicial != null)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Preco >= pesquisa.PrecoInicial);
}
if (pesquisa.PrecoFinal != null)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Preco <= pesquisa.PrecoFinal);
}
query.ToList();
```

Exemplo da query gerada em uma **tabela minha**

```
SELECT [m].[ViaturasID],[m].[ValorPrestacao]
FROM [Viaturas] AS [m]
WHERE ([m].[ValorPrestacao] >= @__prestacaoInicial_0) AND ([m].[ValorPrestacao] <= @__prestacaoFinal_1)
```

Caso queira usar .ToListAsync() mude o final para

```
await query.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Isto será extremamente ineficiente e gerará uma *query* terrível.

Comment: Se você acha que uma *query* que tem verificações desnecessárias está limpa, e que por causa disto não consegue utilizar possíveis índices, então tá.

Comment: Estou aqui para tentar ajudar. Se ele quer buscar por todos os parametros em conjunto todos tem que estar na mesma query. 

Ele não quer buscar por Nome = XX ou Material = Y. Ele quer buscar Nome = X e Material = Y.

Comment: Ninguém questionou se você está aqui para ajudar ou não. Ele quer montar um condição dinamicamente, ele tem vários campos em uma estrutura na memória, aí se o dado não for nulo ele deve entrar na condição, se o dado não for nulo não tem porque usá-lo, ele não deve entrar na condição, o seu tudo está entrando na condição. Experimenta gerar a *query* com 2 ou mais condições.

Comment: Sim, eu mostrei um problema no código, você começou fazer questionamentos especulativos, e continua, a hostilidade parte de sua parte que quer ver problema em um simples questionamento de um problema no seu código. Se você se ater ao problema e ao código e não às pessoas a hostilidade cessa, e assim não criará discussão que não deseja. Se alguém desrespeitou você sinalize a postagem que um outro moderador avaliará a situação. Aqui no SOpt nós avaliamos as soluções para sempre obter o melhor possível, se não deseja que as pessoas avaliem o que você posta terá problemas aqui.

Answer (score 0):

```
 await _context.Produtos 
.Where(x => (pesquisa.Nome == null || x.Nome == pesquisa.Nome)
       &&   (pesquisa.Material  == null || x.Material == pesquisa.Material)
       &&   (pesquisa.Estado == null || x.Estado == pesquisa.Estado)
       &&   (pesquisa.PrecoInicial == 0 || x.Preco >= pesquisa.PrecoInicial)
       &&   (pesquisa.PrecoFinal == 0 || x.Preco <= pesquisa.PrecoFinal))
.ToListAsync();``
```

Faça igual a uma consulta no SQL, se ele for nulo ele não fará nada na pesquisa, caso exista dados ele fará a comparação de cada um deles.
Obs: comparação de valores Decimal == 0 pois ele não pode ser nulo.

Comment: Desta forma os nulos farão parte da consulta e não é o que ele deseja.

Comment: @Maniero não, dessa forma se um parametro vier nulo ele não fará nada, caso ele for diferente de nulo ele faz a comparação

Comment: Você não entendeu a questão, ele fará parte da consulta, ele é ineficiente, ele gera uma consulta ruim, eu já comentei na outra resposta. O AP quer que a consulta seja construída só com os dados existentes, que seja eficiente, por isso precisa gerar dinamicamente, se for assim não é uma geração dinâmica, é estática com verificação posterior em todas as linhas de algo que pode ser feito uma única vez antes e que provavelmente vai impedir o uso de um índice, e pode ficar tudo trágico.

Comment: Não concordo com seu ponto de vista, a validação é da variavel de pesquisa, caso ela for nula ela não fará parte da query, eu ja usei muitas vezes desse modo e nunca gerou consultas lentas ou algo do tipo, porém posso estar errado ou realmente não ter entendido a questão.

Comment: Não é ponto de vista, é como o EF funciona. Você entende como ele gera a *query*? E você mediu usando assim e da forma correta? Porque o que mais vejo hoje em dia é as pessoas usarem coisas piores e nem se darem conta.

Comment: eu entendo como a query funciona, eu ja testei e faço varias das mesmas em sistemas gigantescos e complexos, mas é isso amigo, se você sabe mais que eu tudo bem, estou aqui pra tentar ajudar apenas, não precisar ser rude assumindo que você sabe tudo e as pessoas são leigas.

Comment: Ninguém estava sendo rude, até agora, eu estou apenas discordando do que postou, não pode? Tem que aceitar o que você diz sem contestar? Só você sabe e ninguém pode dizer o contrário? Mostre onde eu assumi que eu sei tudo e você sabe nada? Eu até fiz uma pergunta para entender o seu conhecimento. Bom, eu já mostrei o problema da resposta pra outras pessoas saberem que assim não é adequado, agora é com elas entenderem se você está certo ou não, seria melhor que esse problema fosse resolvido, mas você pode deixar como achar melhor.