# Busca por like com LINQ utilizando array

Tags: c#, linq

**Contexto:**

Possuo o seguinte formulário:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Nessa tela o usuário pode filtrar materiais por algumas de suas propriedades.
O filtro destacado na imagem permite que os usuários busquem por um o mais códigos de fabricação, sendo que, para mais de um código é necessário separar os valores com **;**.

Além disso há um botão ao lado que indica se a busca por esses valores deve retornar só o que for exatamente igual ou o que conter aqueles códigos.

**Exemplo:**

Imagine os seguintes dados e filtros:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Foi preenchido "1234;111" e o botão **exato** está selecionado, portanto, a saída esperada é somente o material **bbbb** que possuí o código 111.

Foi preenchido "1234;111" e o botão **contém** está selecionado, portanto, a saída esperada é somente os materiais **aaaa** e **bbbb**.

A dúvida é como fazer esse segundo filtro com *LINQ*, considerando o código abaixo:

```
var itens = 
   from it in db.TABELA
   join f in db.TABELA2
   on it.id equals f.id
   where it.Ativo == true
   select new { it, f};



if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filtro.CdProdutoFabricante))
{
   var codigosProdutoFabricante = filtro.CdProdutoFabricante.Replace(" ", "").Split(';');

   if (filtro.TipoBuscaCdProdutoFabricante == 0) 
   {
      //Busca por like
   }
   else //Busca por valor exato
   {
      itens = itens.Where(x => codigosProdutoFabricante.Contains(x.it.cdProdutoFabricante));
   }

}
```

Comment: Esse "código de fabricação" é varchar mesmo, né?

Comment: Esse filtro é no banco ou em memória? Não tem como inferir isso pelo código apresentado.

Comment: Varchar. A variavel **itens** é o retorno de uma consulta linq to entities, sendo que na expressão lambda o **x.it** it representa a tabela de materiais

Comment: Mas é o retorno já materializado em memória ou é um Queryable ainda? Isso faz bastante diferença.

Comment: é um IQueryable.

Comment: Neste caso acho que vai ser complicado de montar uma lógica que seja traduzida para SQL sem precisar construir uma expressão.

Comment: Acho que  deveria ler isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/361559/101 ou é mais simples ainda.

Comment: @Maniero Não sei se deixei escapar algo, mas me parece que a consulta que o AP precisa seria uma 'concatenação' de OR. Aí não é tão simples quanto fazer várias chamadas ao método Where

Comment: @LINQ Por isso que eu coloquei o parágrafo final na resposta lá :)

Comment: x.it.cdProdutoFabricante é a uma String e se for String irá conter o padrão de pesquisa do LIKE?

Comment: @LINQ Sim, é exatamente como você disse uma 'concatenação de condições com OR'. O link que o Manieiro postou na outra resposta com PredicateBuilder atende a situação, acredito que a própria resposta aqui postada também sirva não cheguei a testá-la ainda. Acabou que não vou mais implementar esse filtro na aplicação pois acho ele pouco performático e consegui convencer o solicitante.

Comment: Apaguei a resposta porque ela não foi adequada.

Comment: Como eu comentei, @CaiqueRomero. Você vai ter que construir a expressão, talvez a lib da resposta do Maniero te ajude. Eu queria fazer uns testes e tentar responder, mas meu dia não tá deixando =/

Comment: AugustoVasques tranquilo, @LINQ relaxa man, o link do Manieiro ajudou sim, agradeço a vocês pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Caique, pesquisando a respeito do seu problema eu achei [essa solução](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838292/entity-framework-4-1-linq-contains-and-startswith) (em inglês)

No seu caso seria aplicado dessa forma:

```
itens = itens.Where(x => codigosProdutoFabricante.Any(z => z.StartWith(x.it.cdProdutoFabricante)));
```

Lembrando que, como isso será interpretado pelo banco de dados, vai depender se este método foi implementado pelo *provider*.

Espero ter ajudado.